# Python - why list method returns nothing?

Tags: python

I found that from statement `li = str.split()`, a list of elements are assigned to `li`  , while from `li = li.insert(2, "whatever")`, it actually gets me nothing, there's  no value in the list `li` after the second statement. Why is there the difference between these two?

Comment: `li = li.insert(2, "whatever")` => `insert` modifies the list in place and returns `None`, so you assign `None` to `li`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`li.insert`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html) doesn't *return* but *modifes*  `li`:

```
s = "foo bar baz"
l = s.split()
l == ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
l.insert(2, "qux")  
l == ['foo', 'bar', 'qux', 'baz']
```